# 'Make it happen' or 'make it happens'

Tags: objects, imperative-sentences, causative-make

We use the phrase **make it happen**.

But why don't we use **happens** since it has the third-person pronoun **it**?

Why not

> Make it **happens**

Comment: It is imperative mood! http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood

Comment: The second verb in such constructions is always infinitive.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Which construction?

Comment: Hint: "He made it happen" --> "It was made ___."

Comment: In the Imperative, the subject is the Second Person "You" and is usually implied.

Comment: The third person pronoun is not part of a conjugation: It is on the couch. It is a direct object: I hid it behind the couch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is tough!

I think it goes same with *let*. The only thing I can make out is *make* or *let* does not **directly** involve the third person. Said that, the third person is not doing things but they are indirectly involved, without their consciousness. I'm not sure how to put it correctly in words!

> Make *him study* -he does or does not study, yet
>  Let *her go* -she is not directly involved in 'going'
>  and so on...

All above mentioned examples don't involve the third person doing things directly. The rule is when they do it directly, we apply ***'s***. And thus, when we say "*make/let it happen*, the *it* does not perform action ***directly*** as the subject.

Say--

> *It goes* - a subject doing things directly, by itself 
>  *Let it go* - Here, the subject does not do things directly

[This is the best thing I could come up with! Native's inputs will be very useful and I'm so curious for their comments!]

Comment: Yes: **make**, **let**, and **help** all work the same way. If their object is the subject of a subordinate clause, the object takes the objective case and the verb inside the subordinate clause takes the infinitive. It's really just grammar rather than any subtleties of meaning or what controls what.

Comment: Sad to see that this answer was accepted, when the other answer is so much better. Sorry, but "the third person is not doing things but they are indirectly involved, without their consciousness" is both muddled and inaccurate. If I tell my co-worker: "We need that equipment fixed before tomorrow – make it happen," that's the second person, through and through.

Comment: You said *make it happen* so...here *it* does not serve as a subject. That's what I said.

Comment: _The hearer .. is not in control of the matter, no do they take action_ – that's WRONG; the hearer is the subject of the sentence, and the hearer is expected to take action. _the third person is not doing things but they are indirectly involved, without their consciousness_ – that's WRONG; the third person has nothing to do with the matter. A learner could be led astray by this answer.

Comment: For instance, if I say, *Let him go*. By *control* I meant that they are not ***directly*** performing an action. Editing for clarification

Answer (score 10):

Because *it* is not the subject of the sentence. This is an [imperative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood) (a command or directive), given to the listener. The *you* is ellipted, because it's understood by both parties that the second is receiving an instruction from the first.

- Make it happen.
- You make it happen.

These two sentences have the same meaning (when given as commands).

It wouldn't make any sense for *it* to be the subject of the sentence, if you think about it. The thing that needs to happen usually doesn't have any agency; it can't perform any actions. For example, let *it* in *make it happen* mean *reach one million dollars of sales*. You can see that it makes no sense to say that the sales target should reach itself, but it makes a lot of sense to instruct a sales team to sell a certain amount.

We conjugate verbs in accordance with the agent performing the action. Commands are directed to someone, so they use the *you* form. *It* is the object of the command; the thing "receiving" the action, not the thing performing it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the causative verbs "make", "have", and "let", as *causative*, go with object + bare infinitive:
Causative verb + object + bare infinitive /
I will make it happen /
I let her go /
I will have my dinner prepared (in this case the past participle replaces the substantive form of the verb)

Answer (score 0):

As Juan pointed out in [their answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/285912/106592), these kinds of verbs are called ‘causative verbs’ and they take *object + bare infinitive*. I will mark ill-formed/incorrect sentences with an asterisk (*). Let's analyse the sentence “he made me do X”:

- *he made **me** [object] **do X** [bare infinitive]*<sup>1</sup>

not

- **he made me **to** do X*

If you're unsure, replace ‘made’ with **caused me to**:

- *he [**caused me to**] do X*
- **he [**caused me to**] to do X*

the second sentence is ill-formed and incorrect in standard English

I'd also like to point out that it's true for ‘make’ only in active voice. The use of *to* is obligatory in passivised constructions:<sup>2</sup>:

- *he was made **to do** X*

not

- **he was made **do** X*

Now,

- **Make it happens*

In the OP's sentence, ‘make’ can be analysed as being *cause it to*:

- **[**Cause it to**] happens*

this is ungrammatical because we always<sup>3</sup> use infinitive after *to* in present tense, so the correct one is:

- *Make it [= **cause it to**] happen*

---

NOTES:

1. When the base form/infinitive is used without *to*, it's referred to as [‘bare infinitive’](https://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive-2/) as in *I saw **him dance*** (not **I saw him **to** dance*)
2. See CGEL: ‘Note also that when causative verbs like ***make*** and ***let*** are passivised, infinitival *to* switches from being disallowed in the complement to being required’ (p1186).
3. Well, not *always*; there are sentences like *I'm looking forward **to meeting** him*, where we use gerund after *to*, but that's tangential to what we're discussing here

Answer (score -1):

'Make happen' is a phrasal verb. Use it in a sentence, 'make it happen' is imperative sentence. Therefore the structure remains to be 'make happen'; not possible to add an s 'make it happens' or 'you make it happens'. 'It' is not the subject in this sentence so as to conform with the third person use of verb. The word 'happen' though it's a verb form which can either be used as transitive or intransitive can function as an adjective in this sense: Make it happen. Make it beautiful. Some Verbs, as part of speech, can function as an adjective or even as a noun. It depends on use.

Comment: *Make happen* is not a phrasal verb. *Happen* is never transitive. *Happen* is not an adjective, it's a non-finite verb: *Make it very beautiful* or *Make it more beautiful*, but not *\*Make it very happen* or *\*Make it more happen*. What is unusual with *make* is that it takes a bare infinitival clause as a complement; *to*-infinitival clauses are more common.