# How to use the word seem

Tags: third-person-singular

I know that in the following phrase I must add the letter **s** to the verb **seem** when used with third person singular like this:

> It seems to me...

But then I see such phrases as

> make it seem...

and I'm entirely baffled why the word seem is used without the letter **s**. Isn't *seem* used with third person singular here?

Note: English is my third language, but I have a good command of it. Still such peculiarities are perplexing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make it happen?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41541/make-it-happen)

Comment: **Let him go**, **let me do it**, **let's see**, etc. — do these bother you as well?

Comment: The confusion is probably due to the fact that "it" is both a subject and an object. "It seems to me" and "make it seem" are akin to "he seems to me" or "make him seem", respectively.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your example, the verb form of "seem" in "make it seem" is the so-called "bare infinitive" which is required when you use the word "make" with the meaning "to cause someone to do something".

You can read about this use of "make" [here](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/let-and-make.html) (and lots of other places too).

One of the examples given there is "His mother made him clean his room."

Similarly, the phrase "make it seem" would be part of a longer sentence, maybe something like: "The yellowed paper and the mildew stains **make it seem** like an ancient document, but it's a forgery." In that example, "The yellowed paper and the mildew stains" is the subject of the sentence. "Make" agrees with that subject, and "seem" is a bare infinitive as discussed in the reference above.

Comment: It's not confined to "make" and "let". He saw it fly. He heard her sing. She watched it crash.

Comment: An instructive contrasting example would be that if you cut "and the mildew stains", then "make", but not "seem", needs an `-s`: "The yellowed paper __makes__ it seem like ..."

Comment: it can refer to many things. In the OP's example, it can refer to an underlying situation. For example: You make it [undefined] so easy. The it refers to whatever being discussed. The it in your example is therefore a bit confusing.

Answer (score 7):

When using the third person, you would add the **s** to the word *make*, not *seem*.

For example:

> You make it seem easy, I make it seem easy. She **makes** it seem easy, too.

Comment: I would add that the phrase is fundamentally different. With “it seems” the verb is “seem”. So “seem” gets the s. With “she makes it seem” the verb is “make” which is why make gets the s. You could use “she seems nice” too.

Comment: Thanks, @Fogmeister... This is exactly the idea I've got after posting the question